# Namespace and classes in php

Tags: php, class, namespaces

Why i receive error? the class in the same namespace..

php 5.3.0

```
namespace ExampleSystem\Core;
class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        print 'Test ok';
    }
}

// Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in ...
$class_name = 'Test';
$obj = new $class_name;

// Ok
$class_name = 'ExampleSystem\Core\Test';
$obj = new $class_name;

// Ok
$obj = new Test;
```

Comment: So *that's* what the fabled namespaces look like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find chapter and verse in the PHP manual, but the obvious explanation is that when you do:

```
 $obj = new $string
```

then the value of `$string` is not mapped into the current namespace.  This makes sense, when you consider that `$string` may have been passed in from somewhere else, where a different namespace may have been in effect.

Comment: i would have expected it to eval in the context of the namespace it's in but php rarely seems to do what i expect, and since i expect that now, can usually make it do what i want. :)

Comment: Thanks!
I found an example on the php.net site... Magic constant __NAMESPACE__ is the answer :)
http://il2.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php
Example 3